# Opening PDF files on android webview without using GoogleDocViewer

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

How to show `pdf` on `Android webview` from url without using GoogleDocViewer?

`PDF` url needs authentication, and url is working fine on browser but when i'm trying to open the same url in android  webview, it is showing blank screen.

Comment: I just cleared the question on edit for those guys who wanted to do this in future.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mozilla's [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/).

Sample project on how you do it in [Android](https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer/src/89de16a0ea7a631fe0029a119fbd30fef6727b2a/src/com/sample/pdfwebviewer/PdfViewer.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default). Sample project made by user [Butelo](https://bitbucket.org/butelo/).

As user *LinX64* pointed out, this is only usable on `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN` and above.

Answer (score 1):

You should use third-party libraries for these stuffs i guess, by the way, the native android browser doesn't support this `pdf` format.

For example, for completing above users answer, this is only available on + `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN`

Check this too:

> //The default value is true for API level android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1 and below, 
>           //and false for API level android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN and above.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
```